# Password security when connecting to ldap with rails application

Tags: passwords, password-management, ldap, ruby, rails

How do you store a username/password securely in a rails app when using it for many ldap searches?

The connection in the app requires

```
ldap_bind_authenticate(Net::LDAP.new, username, password)
```

each time a search is made, and the credentials of the user are not stored at logon. I often see developers using a test user for the searches and storing a plaintext username/password pair in the user.rb model. Is there a more secure way to do this?

Comment: I've heard of people storing the hashed and salted creds in an environment variable on the machine, but I'm not sure if this is any better.

Comment: How would the hashed creds help? This is the client to the ldap. The LDAP server wouldn't accept a hashed password. It take the password and hashes it. If you give it a hashed password, it will hash it again.

Comment: Yeah you're right - right now I'm decided on storing the creds in a conf file with locked down permissions

Comment: Environment variables are generally the way to go. Config files are too easy to accidentally (or worse, intentionally) commit to your repository, which is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have never used ruby / ruby on rails and in this answer I describe how I would act in general.*

You have two ways to solve this problem:

1. Use an additional user for all your searches.

   - Pro: You don't have to store the users credentials after he/she logged in.
   - Con: I don't know if this matters in your application but you can't track which user has started a caused the query based on your LDAP logs.
   - Implementation: Your have to store sensitive credentials for an external service inside your application. This is the exact same problem as with database credentials so I think you should store your LDAP credentials in the same manner as them.
2. Use the logged in user for searches

   - Pro: You can track what every user has done using your LDAP logs
   - Con: You have to store the unencrypted user information somewhere while the user is logged in.
   - Implementation: Save the unencrypted user information in the session or something so you can access them when you need to.

Personally I would prefer the first solution as it does not involve storing a lot of plaintext user passwords somewhere.